# Gulp detects file change but runs the old version

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a gulp file named `gulpfile.babel.js` (I use babel to transpile my es6 code)

```
import log from './src/log';
import gulp from 'gulp';

gulp.task('writeJson', function (file) {
    log();
});

gulp.task('default', ['writeJson'], function () {
    gulp.watch('./src/**/*.js', ['writeJson'])
});
```

`log` file as it's most simplefied form logs a statement.

```
export default function () {
    console.log('log v1');
}
```

Now when `log` file is modified, `writeJson` task is ran,  But it executes the old function. (Updates to the file aren't applied.)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, Why does gulp file doesn't run the modified new function?

Comment: I've found the answer, will post as soon as I get free.